# how to get cpu_persent using psutil via python

Tags: python, psutil

I wanted to get the overall cpu_percent of the process, so I used the code below but it keeps returning a value of 0.0

```
listOfProcessNames = list()
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        pInfoDict = proc.as_dict(attrs=['username', 'pid', 'name', 'cpu_percent', 'memory_percent'])
        listOfProcessNames.append(pInfoDict)
    listOfProcessNames = sorted(listOfProcessNames, key=lambda procObj: procObj['cpu_percent'], reverse=True)
for elem in listOfProcessNames[:20] :
    print(elem)
```

So I added the code below to get cpu_persent but this is too slow Is there any other way?

```
current_process = psutil.Process(pid=pInfoDict['pid'])

pInfoDict["cpu_percent"] = current_process.cpu_percent(interval=0.1)
```

Comment: Are you trying to get CPU usage for a particular process, or for all processes?

Comment: Get cpu_percent of all processes and try to sort only 20 in order of high usage

Comment: @kimGT: ***`current_process = psutil.Process(`***: This is double work, you have allready a reference to the current process in `proc`. The docu claims *"considerably speeds up the retrieval "* using [`oneshot()`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.oneshot)

Comment: thank you for answer
I tried using psutil.oneshot () cpu.percent to get a specific process ID, but it always prints 0.0

Comment: ***"always returned `0.0`"***: Read the [`psutil.Process.cpu_percent` **`Warning`**](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.cpu_percent). To get a reasonable value you have to call at least twice between a amount of timespan.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I'm too slow to use a 0.1 second interval, so I want to get the amount of cpu in use in one request.